# Order bar chart using react-charts-js-2 ChartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating bar graphs obtaining data for the month and it works fine but the order is never by the order of the months and it is also messed up in each rendering.

The data I receive from the API is the following:

```
{
{
    "_id": 2022,
    "sales": [
        {
            "month": "Dic",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 8737.6
        },
        {
            "month": "Oct",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 1936.0000000000002
        },
        {
            "month": "Sep",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 526.8000000000001
        },
        {
            "month": "Nov",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 2205.2000000000003
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So I use this code with react-chartjs-2 (chartjs) like this:

```
  const data = {
      labels: dataOfSalesPerMonth?.map((data) => data.month),
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Venta Mensual",
          data: dataOfSalesPerMonth?.map((data) => data.total),
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            "#ecf0f1",
            "#50AF95",
            "#f3ba2f",
            "#2a71d0",
          ],
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 2,
        },
      ]
    }
```

And in react I render it like this:

```
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-44">
      {
        Object.entries(sales).length &&
          <Bar
            data={data}
            options={options}
          />
      }
    </div>
  )
```

But the order is not correct, it always gives me the months mixed up and never in the same order:

[image: Bar]

How can I order it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add custom sorting logic

```js
const data = {
    "_id": 2022,
    "sales": [
        {
            "month": "Dic",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 8737.6
        },
        {
            "month": "Oct",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 1936.0000000000002
        },
        {
            "month": "Sep",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 526.8000000000001
        },
        {
            "month": "Nov",
            "year": 2022,
            "total": 2205.2000000000003
        }
    ]
}


const sortByMonth = (arr) => {
  const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
  arr.sort((a, b)=>{
      return months.indexOf(a.month)
           - months.indexOf(b.month);
  });
}


sortByMonth(data.sales);

console.log(data.sales);
```